# chmod not changing permissions for files in Google Drive File Stream

Tags: unix, chmod

I am trying to change permissions of files that I keep on Google Drive File Stream (where I keep 99% of files on my laptop).  However, chmod doesn't appear to be changing the permissions. For example, I have this test file in a folder, and `ls -l` returns:

```
-rw-------  1 mattdesaix  staff     0B Jan 28 17:51 FILE-rw-rw-r--
-rwx------  1 mattdesaix  staff     0B Jan 28 17:51 FILE-rwxrwxr--
```

I want to change the permissions for the files to match their name, so I tried:

```
chmod 774 FILE-rwxrwxr--
chmod 664 FILE-rw-rw-r--
```

But to no avail. Now there is an * at the name of the second file.

```
-rw-------  1 mattdesaix  staff     0B Jan 28 17:51 FILE-rw-rw-r--
-rwx------  1 mattdesaix  staff     0B Jan 28 17:51 FILE-rwxrwxr--*
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with working through Google Drive File Stream but browsing forums hasn't brought up anything that seemed related.  Maybe it's something simple I'm missing...

Any input would be appreciated on why `chmod` wouldn't be changing permissions. Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Try to exec command on this way: `chmod 774 -- FILE-rwxrwxr--`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that results in ```No such file or directory```